# console returns an error when npm run deploy

Tags: git, npm, deployment

I have problems with deploy.

gh-pages -d build

git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vkappcodesford@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vkappcodesford@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yokum\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-18T19_29_30_578Z-debug.log
[screenshot console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv3H8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If such a problem arises, then it is easier to deploy it with Bash. This could solve the problem.